Python how to make the code work in one program and not in others
I am learning Python, I wrote the code for afk farm (minecraft). And I want to collapse the tab (minecraft) and watch YouTube there, or play another game so that the code continues to work in minecraft, but does not work in other programs, how to do this, thank you!
import pyautogui as ptg
import keyboard as key

isclicking = False

def check_clicking():
  global isclicking
if isclicking == True:
    isclicking = False
else:
    isclicking = True
key.add_hotkey('F10', check_clicking)

while True:
  if isclicking == True:
    ptg.doubleClick()



Identify the program window
Check the active window
Continue clicking only the program

First install pygetwindow:

pip install pygetwindow

Here's the implementation:
import pyautogui as ptg
import keyboard as key
import pygetwindow as gw
import time
isclicking = False
def check_clicking():
    global isclicking
    isclicking = not isclicking
key.add_hotkey('F10', check_clicking)
def is_minecraft_active():
    try:
        return 'Minecraft' in gw.getActiveWindow().title
    except AttributeError:
        return False
while True:
    if  isclicking and is_minecraft_active():
        ptg.doubleClick()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    time.sleep(0.01)

